# How can i split a column in more columns based on a specific value in certain cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

[image]

I have a column with many agents that all have different results, i need to split that column in multiple columns that show all the info until next agent - as in the picture.

Thanks in advance.

I'm new to excel and couldn't find a solution myself.

|  |
| --- |
| Agent: Martin |
| 10 |
| 223 |
| 33 |
| 125 |
| 2 |
| Agent: Joe |
| 2 |
| 23 |
| Agent: Mark |
| 1 |
| 23 |
| 111 |
| 444 |
| 21 |
| 32 |
| Agent: Sasha |
| 3 |
| 222 |
| 121 |
| 654 |
| 32 |
| 98 |
| 76 |

| Agent: Martin | Agent: Joe | Agent: Mark | Agent: Sasha |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 223 | 23 | 23 | 222 |
| 33 |  | 111 | 121 |
| 125 |  | 444 | 654 |
| 2 |  | 21 | 32 |
|  |  | 32 | 98 |
|  |  |  | 76 |

with the new formula in C1 it stops importing results when it hits a cell with text.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the functions Excel offers? index() and match() ncome to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something along the lines, assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per tags posted, then this should work for you:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,TOCOL(A:A,1),
     b,SCAN("",a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISNUMBER(y),x,y))),
     c,UNIQUE(b),
     DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",c,LAMBDA(d,e,HSTACK(d,FILTER(a,e=b)))),""),,1))
```

---

Or, you can use this as well, one step less:

```
=LET(
     a,TOCOL(A:A,1),
     b,SCAN("",a,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(ISNUMBER(y),x,y))),
     UNIQUE(DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",b,LAMBDA(d,e,HSTACK(d,FILTER(a,e=b)))),""),,1),1))
```

---

Alternative approach for **`Non-MS365`** users:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$24,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$A$24)-ROW($A$1)+1)/(ISTEXT($A$1:$A$24)),COLUMN(A1)))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$24,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$A$24)-ROW($A$1)+1)/
 (LOOKUP(ROW($A$1:$A$24),ROW($A$1:$A$24)/(IF(ISNUMBER($A$1:$A$24),"",$A$1:$A$24)<>""),$A$1:$A$24)=C$1),ROW(A2))),"")
```

---

Note that, the formula for the header needs to be filled right while the formula for the numbers needs to fill down as well as filled right accordingly, also changes cell reference and ranges accordingly as per your data. One more caveat, one needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

Since OP has not updated in their original post and have some anomaly with their data here is an updated solution.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$24,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$A$24)-ROW($A$1)+1)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Agent",$A$1:$A$24))),COLUMN(A1)))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$24,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$A$24)-ROW($A$1)+1)/
 (LOOKUP(ROW($A$1:$A$24),ROW($A$1:$A$24)/(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Agent",$A$1:$A$24)),"",$A$1:$A$24)<>""),$A$1:$A$24)=C$1),ROW(A2))),"")
```

---

All prior caveats are applied based on ones excel version.

Comment: Really apreciate the answer. I`m new here and as u mention i forgot to mention that i use Excel 2013, and this doesn`t seemn to work for me.

Comment: @GeorgianStoica posted alternative solution for your version of Excel. Let me know if that resolves

Comment: Is there any chance that the C2 formula takes into acount that results can have text too ?Agent: Martin
Offline
223
33
Offline
2
Agent: Joe
2
23
Agent: Mark
1
Offline
111
444
21
32
Agent: Sasha
3
222
121
off
32
98
76

Comment: I am afraid this is a different question which was not mentioned earlier, dont ever do this, others may mark you down, however here is the updated formula. `C1`-->`=INDEX($A$1:$A$24,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$A$24)-ROW($A$1)+1)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Agent",$A$1:$A$24))),COLUMN(A1)))`

Comment: `C2`--> `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$24,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$A$24)-ROW($A$1)+1)/
 (LOOKUP(ROW($A$1:$A$24),ROW($A$1:$A$24)/(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Agent",$A$1:$A$24)),"",$A$1:$A$24)<>""),$A$1:$A$24)=C$1),ROW(A2))),"")`

Comment: @GeorgianStoica glad to know it worked out for you =)